# Знакомство с Small Basic C#

Tags: c#, small-basic

Всем привет.
 Знакомлюсь с Small Basic на C# читаю инструкцию но она описана на другом языке.
Подскажите как описать этот код на C# (не понимаю как создать массив квадратов)

```vb
  rows = 8 
  columns = 8 
  size = 40

  For r = 1 To rows   
  For c = 1 To columns     
  GraphicsWindow.BrushColor = GraphicsWindow.GetRandomColor()     
  boxes[r][c] = Shapes.AddRectangle(size, size)     
  Shapes.Move(boxes[r][c], c * size, r * size)   
  EndFor 
  EndFor
```

Результат двумерный рандомоцветный кубик рубик.

Comment: Как я понял  Small Basic это отдельный язык который не c#. Вы хотите пройтись по уроках курса по Small Basic используя c#?

Comment: @ Andrew Romanenko Да

Comment: По поводу моего ответа комментарии будут? Если там всё хорошо, то его стоит принять нажатием на галочку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю, примерно так. Точнее сказать не могу, т. к. не знаю, что перевожу.

```
int rows = 8;
int columns = 8;
int size = 40;
Shape[,] boxes = new boxes[rows, columns];

for (int r=0; r<rows; ++r) // For r = 0 To rows - 1
  for (int c=0; c<columns; ++c) // For c = 0 To columns - 1
    {
    GraphicsWindow.BrushColor = GraphicsWindow.GetRandomColor();
    boxes[r, c] = Shapes.AddRectangle(size, size);
    Shapes.Move(boxes[r, c], (c+1) * size, (r+1) * size); // Почему?
    }
```